# Typescript interface type with optional keys of different types and strictNullChecks

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create the following interface in typescript:

```
type MoveSpeed = "min" | "road" | "full";

interface Interval {
  min?: number,
  max?: number
}

interface CreepPlan {
  [partName: string] : Interval;
  move?:    MoveSpeed;
}
```

However, this syntax is invalid. The compiler says `Property 'move' of type '"min" | "road" | "full" | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Interval'.`.

I am using the compiler option `strictNullChecks:true`, which is why `undefined` is included implicitly for the `move?` key.

However, this syntax is valid:

```
type MoveSpeed = "min" | "road" | "full";

interface Interval {
  min?: number,
  max?: number
}

interface CreepPlan {
  [partName: string] : Interval;
  move:    MoveSpeed;            // 'move' is required
}
```

I want to express the idea "CreepPlan consists of string:Interval pairs, except the optional 'move' key which is a string:MoveSpeed pair." Is it possible to express this in typescript?

Comment: I think the problem might be where (and how) you're using that code, not the code itself, since your example compiles without error

Comment: @ssube Apologies, I am using `strictNullChecks` set to true. I will clarify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You stated that all properties on `CreepPlan` have `Interval`-type values when you wrote:

```
interface CreepPlan {
  [partName: string] : Interval;
}
```

i.e., any and every string-index-accessible property of `CreepPlan` will be an `Interval`. This applies to `move` as well, since `foo['move']` is the same as `foo.move`.

However, looking at `Interval`, there's no required structure to it:

```
interface Interval {
  min?: number,
  max?: number
}
```

There are no required fields in that contract, but it *does* require an object. It will happily accept an empty object, but it requires some object that *could* have a `min` and `max` properties.

Your `MoveSpeed` type, on the other hand, allows `undefined`:

> Property 'move' **of type '"min" | "road" | "full" | undefined'** is not assignable to string index type 'Interval'.

Thus, `Interval` must be an object with no required properties (which `string` can easily meet) but does not allow `undefined`, which `MoveSpeed` *does* allow.

Your types are disjoint, but it's not obvious until you resolve them out once or twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was also my intuition, but what I don't understand is why the second example in my question (with `move` as a required member) is valid. Perhaps some quirk of the typescript compiler.

Comment: @Oliver I think I know. Editing it in, just a sec.

Answer (score 12):

As described in the typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) if you use indexable properties then all the return type of all the other properties should be assignable to the return type of the index return type.
That's because `foo['bar']` and `foo.bar` are the same.

So why does this work?

```
interface CreepPlan {
    [partName: string]: Interval;
    move: MoveSpeed;
}
```

Because any `MoveSpeed` is a valid `Interval` value (it is an interval with undefined both `min`/`max`.

Why doesn't this work?

```
interface CreepPlan {
     [partName: string]: Interval;
     move?: MoveSpeed;
 }
```

`move?` has type `MoveSpeed` plus the `undefined` type. If is has the undefined value then it is not assignable to `Interval`  so the compiler correctly shows error.

How can you fix this? Simply make the indexer have `undefined` as a valid value:

```
interface CreepPlan {
    [partName: string]: Interval | undefined;
    move?: MoveSpeed;
}
```