# Troubles with creating Typescript interface with specified and unspecified keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create an interface for a component's state which looks like this:

```
interface ComponentState {
  booleanProperty: boolean
  [unspecifiedKey: string]: {
    [name: string]: string
  }
}
```

This also won't work

```
interface UnspecifiedKey { [name: string]: string }

interface ComponentState {
  booleanProperty: boolean
  [unspecifiedKey: string]: UnspecifiedKey
}
```

My state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  booleanProperty: true
  whatever: {value: ''}
}
```

And I receive an error:

> Property 'booleanProperty' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string
>   index type '{ [name: string]: string; }'.
>
> Error TypeScript  Type '{ whatever: { value: string; };
>   booleanProperty: true; }' is not assignable to type
>   'Readonly'. Property 'booleanProperty' is incompatible with
>   index signature. Type 'true' is not assignable to type '{ [name:
>   string]: string; }'.

Typescript doesn't throw an error only when my state looks like this

```
interface ComponentState {
  [unspecifiedKey: string]: {
    [name: string]: string
  } | boolean
}
```

However I consider this solution ugly. Any idea on how can I make my interface neater?

Answer (score 0):

[here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904140/typescript-interface-type-with-optional-keys-of-different-types-and-strictnullch)

for a quick fix you can use

`interface ComponentState {
  booleanProperty: boolean,
  \[unspecifiedKey: string]: any
}`

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't linked an answer to my question. All the properties I declared are required. The object with unspecified keys is required to appear at least once. And I can't use any, because I need to describe the structure of it.

Comment: As described in the typescript [docs][1] if you use indexable properties then all the return type of all the other properties should be assignable to the return type of the index return type. That's because foo['bar'] and foo.bar are the same.


  [1]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

in your case there only "any" as solution.

(idk how to add link in comment)
This was one of the answers there. It has nothing to do with requireable props.

Comment: It should be your answer, not a comment. :) I'd check it as solved.